# Empty space at the end of the page in mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a [html page](http://recruitingascareer.com/landingpage/land/page.html). There is a blank space at the end of the page after footer. You can see that space in Mozilla Firefox at screen sizes `768x1024`, `800x1280`, `980x1280`.

I have tried out everything to get rid of it but failed. This space is not even identified  in the inspect element. Any help will be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. Can you please share screenshots and more information on what have you done so far? Could be the fact that there is not enough content on the page? In that case do a sticky footer - google it :)

Comment: Try to provide a screenshot of the issue for better understanding for people who can't reproduce it.

Comment: Please take a tour on how to ask question. Verify how you wrote your question. You better show some code. And about your problem, have you applied a default `margin/padding: 0` to all of the elements (using `*` selector) ? It can screw up things sometimes

Comment: by "space" do you mean the space below the copyright text?

Comment: Yes @immortal dude.I have just added screenshot of the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the photo, I think this is the expected behavior and is caused by the fact that you do not have enough content to fill the whole page. To fix that, you would need to create a sticky footer  and make the body and html 100% height;

Please see this article for the sticky footer: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Comment: Hello ,I have added sticky footer but it create a problem in it.Now the empty space is added above the footer please see this link https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-EiVC-Vb5COU/WJRnCa_I8_I/AAAAAAAAAV0/CUORMK_1XyY7B4G1rASmESGmpIxPMGnrQCL0B/h768/2017-02-03.png

Comment: Now, make the body & html tags 100%, then adjust the page content (or at least the background) to match the screen height. But basically, your main issue should be resolved by now. Can you please show snippet of the result to check your code for future help?

Comment: I don't know what your design is, but i can see that you only have HEADER tag and the only content is in there. If that would be the final content on the page, you can set height: calc(100vh - 20px); to be always 100% of viewport  screen minus the 20px for the footer. Let me know if you need further help.